# read Nautilus variable from shell script with PHP shebang

Tags: shell, php, nautilus

I have a php code that I have placed inside of a .sh script in order to run it as a file right-click option on Nautilus. Inside of this code, I need to read the content of a $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS variable that Nautilus fills when I 'right-click' a file and run my script. But I don't know how to read it.

My script starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php

try {

$filename_nautilus = $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS;
...
```

But there $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS turns out to be empty. Whereas if I had started the script with the normal shebang, the variable indeed would contain the value that I need:

```
#!/bin/sh

#the variable below contains the value that I need
$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS
```

As you can imagine, I don't know the first thing about shell scripts, but I figure there must be some easy way to do this, so please help me if you can.

PS: I have also tried to run the php script from within the shell script, passing the variable as an argument, but for some reason I couldn't make it work. Anyway, if it's possible to achieve this just reading the value somehow from the php code that seems simpler.

Answer (score 0):

google: "php environment variables". The very first link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php

So:

```
<?php
$filename_nautilus = $_ENV["NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS"];
?>
```

Comment: Actually I had tried this as well, and the result is the same: there is nothing there. $_ENV is an empty array.